# Dynamically append and delete elements from a vector

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any way of dynamically adding elements and at the same time removing some of them? Preferably in MATLAB.

For example, let's say I am streaming data from a sensor. Since it will be streaming forever, I would like to keep only the last, say, 100 samples/elements of the vector.

Comment: you mean a deque ?

Comment: @Shasha99 yes, upon googling the term, this is what I need.

Comment: Wrote the answer. Please mark it answered if you are satisfied.

Comment: You better implement cyclic buffer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no formal [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) data structure for this in Matlab, but the basic case you describe can be implemented quite simply with clever use of indexing and `max`:

```
d = [];  % Allocate empty array
n = 100; % Max length of buffer/queue

% A loop example for illustration
for i = 1:1e3
    x = rand(1,3);                           % Data to append
    d = [d(max(end-n+1+length(x),1):end) x]; % Append to end, remove from front if needed
end
```

The above assumes the appended data, `x`, is a row vector of length 0 to `n`. You can easily modify this to append to the front, etc. It could also be turned into a function as well.

You can also find classes that implement various forms of queues on the MathWorks File Exchange, e.g., [this one](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32273-im2html-m/content/im2html/+se/+utils/Deque.m).

Comment: The problem with this approach is it is going to be very slow.  The point of a queue or dequeue is that it proves an efficient way to append data.  But approach requires copying all the data every time through the loop (it may also create a new array every time, I am not sure).  This is going to be slow.  It may be acceptable for 100-element arrays, but it won't scale.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `Queue` module in python:

```
from Queue import Queue

q=Queue()

to enque at back    :  q.put(x)
to deque from front :  q.get()
```

You may use `deque` from `collections` as well(in case you have some advance requirement) in python:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque([])

to enque at back     : d.append(x)
to enque at front    : d.appendleft(x)
to deque from back   : d.pop()
to deqeue from front : d.popleft()
```